# properly using variable variables for multilanguage feature

Tags: php

I implemented a multilanguage feature for my web application. I get the values by this

```
echo $lang['the key here'];
```

and i keep the values in a separate fiels like this

```
$lang['confirm'] = 'COnfirm the message';
$lang['deny'] = 'Deny the invitation';
```

so i want if somebody calls a undefined key like $lang['sdefscfef'] , insted of printing white space, I want to print the key name i.e 'sdefscfef'

I want to make it as a function

```
function translate($string) {
if(! isset($string)) {
echo THE KEY;
}
else {
echo $string;
}
}

translate($lang['asdadad']);
```

and to print the key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of printing the array directly I would create a function (`_()` is common) and use it like so:

```
echo _('Welcome');
```

And the `_()` function would then look in the $language array:

```
function _ ($str) {
    global $language;

    return isset($language[$str]) ? $language[$str] : $str;
}
```

Something like that.

If you want to avoid using a global variable you can wrap all of this in a class like this:

```
class Lang {
    private $lang = array();

    public static translate ($str) {
        return isset(self::$lang[$str]) self::$lang[$str] : $str;
    }
}
```

And then, to avoid having to type `Lang::translate()` everywhere you can do this:

```
function _ ($str) {
    return Lang::translate($str);
}
```

Here's an example of a little more advanced Language class: http://code.google.com/p/sleek-php/source/browse/trunk/Core/Lang.php

Comment: Actually, `_()` is more common. It's already an alias for `gettext()` though and unfortunately you cannot overwrite a function once it was defined.

Comment: @KingCrunch: Usually I'd agree with you but if it's a small application that does not use OOP, using a global for this is perfectly fine - you can then simply include the appropriate language file.

Comment: @KingCrunch - normally I would wrap this in a class and keep the $language array as a member of that class but for simplicity I used a global var here. ThiefMaster - good point. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use simply:

```
$lang['confirm'] = 'COnfirm the message';
$lang['deny'] = 'Deny the invitation';
....

function getTranslation($key) {
    global $lang;
    if (isset($lang[$key])) {
        return $lang[$key];
    } else {
        return $key;
    }
}

// Usage:
echo getTranslation('confirm'); // Prints 'Confirm the message'
echo getTranslation('sjdhj'); // Prints 'sjdhj'
```